# How to resolve "resolve-url-loader: webpack misconfiguration" warning in webpack configuration?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, webpack, resolve-url-loader

I'm encountering a warning message in my webpack build related to the resolve-url-loader, stating "resolve-url-loader: webpack misconfiguration webpack or the upstream loader did not supply a source-map." Despite this warning, my build seems to be working fine.

Here's the specific warning message:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[1]!./node_modules/scoped-css-loader/index.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[3]!./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[4]!./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css)
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js):
resolve-url-loader: webpack misconfiguration
  webpack or the upstream loader did not supply a source-map
```

I've tried researching online, but I couldn't find a clear solution. Has anyone encountered this warning before, and if so, how did you resolve it? Is there a specific webpack configuration or resolve-url-loader setting I need to adjust to eliminate this warning?

That's my webpack.config.ts:

```
import path from 'path';
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js', // Seu ponto de entrada pode variar
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(sc|c|sa)ss$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'style-loader' },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              importLoaders: 2,
            },
          },
          { loader: 'scoped-css-loader' },
          { loader: 'resolve-url-loader' },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: { sourceMap: true },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: Can you show the versions of these packages?